# Windows 10 file explorer tab on the left

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I will show you a few images of what my file explorer should look like and what it looks like now.

This is what mine looks like:

[image: this is what mine looks like]

This is what it should look like:

[image: this is what it should look like]

As you can see in the first image, I don't have the tab with files in it on my left but you can see it circled with red on the second image. I recently reinstalled my Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

On the Ribbon, click on Navigation pane, then Select Navigation pane. The left pane will be displayed.

[image]

Comment: wow, so simple. thank you so much for helping me out!

Comment: Good that the issue is solved :-) Please visit the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) to learn how to navigate and say thank you on this site.